# Establish SSH Connection Between Two Isolated Machines Using a 3rd System

Tags: python, networking, ssh, portforwarding

I'd like to do the following with Python:

1. Computer 1 starts SSH server (probably using twisted or paramiko)
2. Computer 1 connects to Server 1 (idle connection)
3. Computer 2 connects to Server 1
4. Server 1 forwards Computer 2's connection to Computer 1 (connection no longer idle)
5. Computer 1 forwards Server 1's connection to listening SSH port (on computer 1)

Result being Computer 2 now has a SSH session with Computer 1, almost as if Computer 2 had started a normal SSH session (but with Server 1's IP instead of Computer 1's)

I need this because I can't port forward on Computer 1's network (the router doesn't support it).

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add Computer1 is a Windows machine, Computer2 is a linux machine. I can use 'ssh' on Computer2, but the server on Computer1 needs to be python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, using an example from twisted's (hard to find) example of conch @ http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/conch/scripts/conch.py

I'll be able to extract what I need from that. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ssh` to create a remote tunnel (`-R`) from the server to the local system. If you're insistent on doing this with Python then there's the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Which local system? Computer1 or Computer2? :\ I'll look up the -R switch though

Comment: The "local system" is Computer1. `ssh -R someport:localhost:22 someuser@Server1`

Comment: Oh man, that's neat! I wish I could do that with Python :\ (just read the manpages for ssh -R) The local system server needs to be in python though - no access to install ssh

Comment: Twisted Conch supports this SSH feature.

Comment: Yes, I've been researching that for the past ~15 minutes. I can't find any examples however, so I'm still reading. If you know of any examples, would you link to them please? :)